# Why isn't my css applied unless i clean browser cache?

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome

I'm making a simple website for a school project. It was going well until i added php to the code. Now it doesn't want to apply my css changes every time for some reason. I validated html, css and php on some sites and everything seems to be clean. Then i came across a article that said i have to clear the cache for the css to get applied. It worked (using chrome) though now i have to clean it after every css change or it wont get applied. Only thing that is coming to my mind is that I'm working in PhpStorm but checking the code using xampp and not the PhpStorm built-in browsers, though it worked perfectly until the php. Is there a better way out then clearing cache after every single css change?

Comment: It is not about PHP. It is up to your server e.g. Apache to specify how browsers should cache static files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could edit your server settings but I’d just get in a habit of doing a “[Hard Refresh](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)” instead of a refresh.

When developing websites I always use Hard Refresh over regular refresh to avoid something old getting pulled from the cache. Simply press Ctrl + shift + r for a hard refresh  or see the link above for a list of shortcuts on different systems and browsers.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, I suggest you disable the cache while the developer tools are open.

To do this, open Chrome's developer tools (press F12) then open the Settings (press F1). Find the checkbox labeled `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)` under the `Network` heading.

Once this is turned on, keep the dev tools window open while you do your development work and Chrome will no longer cache your CSS files and always load the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Add a random query string in the link where you are importing the css. That way Chrome will not recognize it as a static asset and will always fetch the newest version from the server.

Be sure to remove it before going live if you need to enhance caching.

Using php it would look like this:

```
<link href="style.css?v=<?=rand(1,1000)?>" />
```

This way one time it will be like `style.css?v=28`, next time `style.css?v=674`, then `style.css?v=18` and so on, thus no browser will cache this style.